# Replace last class by php

Tags: php, replace

```
$list = '<ul>
<li class="woman">photo</li>
<li class="woman">photo</li>
<li class="woman">photo</li>
<li class="woman">photo</li>
<li class="woman">photo</li>
<li class="woman">photo</li>
<li class="woman">photo</li>
<li class="woman">photo</li>
<li class="woman">photo</li>
</ul>';
```

How do I replace last `<li>`'s class from 'woman' to 'man'?

We should get finally:

```
$list = '<ul>
<li class="woman">photo</li>
<li class="woman">photo</li>
<li class="woman">photo</li>
<li class="woman">photo</li>
<li class="woman">photo</li>
<li class="woman">photo</li>
<li class="woman">photo</li>
<li class="woman">photo</li>
<li class="man">photo</li>
</ul>';
```

Comment: Where do you get the string from?

Comment: @Rooney: Yes, but do you generate it yourself?

Comment: Are you using regex (preg_match) or only PHP?

Comment: Why do you need the last class to be different?

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: @Gumbo why do you need to ask me that

Comment: @Messi: Maybe there’s an easier way to achieve what you’re intending to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a regular expression (which is greedy by default), it is quite easy:

```
$list = preg_replace ('#^(.*class=")woman(".*)$#s', '$1man$2', $list);
```

That won't take into account that the class might be on something other than an LI tag or if the last LI tag has no class. To fix the first, you can simply change the regex:

```
$list = preg_replace ('#^(.*<li class=")woman(".*)$#s', '$1man$2', $list);
```

To fix the last:

```
$list = preg_replace ('#^(.*)<li[^>]*>(.*)$#s', '$1<li class="man">$2', $list);
```

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

1. Use regular expressions and formulate the regular expression according to your needs. E.g. replace the last li blocks class attribute with a different value.

   `$list = preg_replace('#^(.*<li class=")(.*)(">.*</li>.*)$#s', '$1man$3', $list);`
2. Generate a DOM-Tree from the fragment and use xpath to adress the last li element. ([DOM - documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

Comment: I dont have an idea how to use all the info you gave me. Can you just give some peace of code, so I can accept your answer?

Comment: I added an example for the first option. The second option would be a little bit bloated for your usecase. If you happen to have more complex search/replace operations inside the html content it would be the appropriate way.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$off = strripos ( $list , "class=");
$list = substr_replace ( $list , "man" , $off+7, 5);
```

I think this is, by far, the simplest way to perform the trick, and no regexp needed at all!

Comment: are you kidding? the is not a solution.

Comment: Sorry, I realized the other version was moronic, but I still think this is the best solution. Why get all complicated with regexps or DOM stuff when old plain string manipulation is all you need?

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't find a suitable duplicate, so here is the DOM solution:

```
$list = '<ul>
<li class="woman">photo</li>
<li class="woman">photo</li>
<li class="woman">photo</li>
<li class="woman">photo</li>
<li class="woman">photo</li>
<li class="woman">photo</li>
<li class="woman">photo</li>
<li class="woman">photo</li>
<li class="woman">photo</li>
</ul>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->loadXml($list);
$dom->documentElement->lastChild->setAttribute('class', 'man');
$dom->formatOutput = true;
echo $dom->saveXml($dom->documentElement);
```

http://codepad.org/6MVEytcp

If your markup is not XML compliant or if its a full html page consider using `loadHTML` to use libxml's HTML parser module. In that case, search around on StackOverflow or through my answers. There is plenty examples.